# Automating identifying Yield Point from a Stress-Strain Curve within VBA

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

I hope that someone can help.

I have tensile test data, I can plot the data, however, I am looking to find a way of automating the process of identifying the yield point and the calculating of the elastic modulus.

Every method I have come across has been to physical pick these points, this makes the process subjective, I am hoping to eliminate this.

I want to write this in VBA and have my colleagues use the macro enable excel sheet to create consentient data points from tensile data.

I have tried to calculating the gradient between each point and then using the differences to identify a yield point, however, the noise of the experimental data makes this impossible. I used a moving average to try and smooth the data, first using 5 points and then 10, but to no avail.

I was hoping to use this yield point as the starting spot for calculating the mod, and thus I have become stuck.

I am hoping that someone has got experience in this and can point me in the right direction, or give me some ideas to filter the data without applying a function to the data.

I have experience in MATLAB so if anyone has completed this in that code then I would appreciate their help too.

Any ideas would be appreciated, even simple pseudo code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code. Perhaps making a template would be a better approach. A quick look and it appears calculating the exact yield point isn't possible, however an estimate is. See this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNIvZyd5djQ

Answer (score 1):

Do a linear least square regression on the linear part of your strain-stress curve. You should use every data point in the linear part. Of course it is difficult to say where the linear part begins or ends. Maybe you know that the range from 10 MPa to 200 MPa is always linear. So you could just that part.

You now have a parametric representation of the curve:

```
y = m * x
```

Where y is stress, x is strain and m is Young's modulus. The linear regression has dealt with the noise.

Now shift the linear eqaution by some margin, say 0.5%. Compute the intersection between the shifted linear equation and the original data. This is the yield point. If you select a smaller margin, the computation will be more accurate, but less stable. You need to adjust the margin to the precision of your test setup.